# Switching plug in automation lanes shortcut in Pro Tools

Tags: pro-tools, automation, pt-quick-keys, shortcut

I'm currently working on a dialogue reel and using the Trim plugin gain automation to level out the dialogue a bit (no PT10 yet! Still on v9). I kinda like the way you can toggle from the Waveform view to the Volume automation view with a simple minus keystroke (keyboard focus on). Is there a way of quickly doing this to a desired plug in automation lane, ie the Trim gain?

I know I can just open up another automation lane below and adjust it there, but that starts to get messy for me. I like to have the automation overlapped on the waveform in this case. Having to click on the Track View and go to the end of the list to switch to the Trim gain automation is becoming tedious :/ I know I can Control + Command + Left/Right arrow to scroll through the list, but I was wondering if there was a one click solution to this?

Any suggestions/workflow tips appreciated!

Cheers
Andy

Answer (score 1):

Control + Command click on the gain slider in the trim plugin window.

Comment: cheers for the reply!

Answer (score 1):

@soundspeed's already got it there. another suggestion -- if you constantly dip in to a particular automation lane, such as your trim gain, you could use your Zoom Toggle ('e') to switch views back and forth quickly.

Just make sure it's set to 'last used' in prefs for the 'zoom toggle' section